# set notation, for indexed family

Tags: algorithms

I'm having trouble to express formally, a trivial algorithm, which is something like this:

parameters:
a **set** of students $S$ that have taken **a** course $c_i$, where course
belongs to a of set courses $C$

Algo:
For each course $c \in C$, add the set of students $S$ that
have taken the course $c$.

Formally I have expressed the algorithm as follows:

**Input:** 
set of courses $C$

set of a sets of students $\mathcal{F = \{ S_c | c \in C\}}$

**Output:** List $L$

1. for each $c_i \in C$

   2. for each $S_j \in \mathcal{F}, j \in i$

      3. List.add($S_j$) // ads a set at the time, not single elem.

**return** L

Can you tell me if the algorithm is expressed correctly?
I would highly appreciate your help!

Comment: Let the courses be $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ and students $S_\alpha = \{1,2,3,4\}$, $S_\beta = \{2,3,5\}$, $S_\gamma = \{1,2,6\}$. What would/should be your final list $L$?

Comment: we iterate first over ($\alpha, \beta, \gamma$), and add to List each set of students that have taken ($\alpha, \beta, \gamma$)

Comment: I can read that in your question, I given the specifics, so that no details are missed. Could you just tell me the intended result for the input I provided?

Comment: the result would be $L = \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few remarks:

- Neither $c$ nor the index $i$ for $c_i \in C$ isn't defined anywhere, so I guess that you wanted just "for any $c \in C$".
- With regard to $j \in i$: notation $x \in y$ doesn't make sense unless $y$ is some collection (a set, list, whatever). Perhaps you meant $j = i$ (or rather $j = c$ taking into account the previous bullet)?
- As you define $\mathcal{F}$ by a set comprehension, there is at most one $\mathcal{S}$ for any color $c \in C$. So you can skip the whole loop, and just use $\mathcal{S}_c$.
- You write `List.add(...)`, but what is `List`? Perhaps you wanted `L.add`, but in mathematical notation you rarely use a dot in such context. Usually you write $L \gets L + \mathcal{S}_j$ together with a comment that explains what $+$ does for lists.
- Finally, *lists* are commonly understood as structures that may contain multiple copies of the same element. If you add $1$ to the list and then add it a second time, the list will have two copies of $1$. Also, lists keep the elements in order. For these reasons, I guess that perhaps you wanted to use another *set*?

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$